# Performance impact of new calculated column with Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm playing around with Python, numpy and more with the intention to get into tensorflow and machine learning and really understand everything, not just the "how to run" parts.

In many cases, I need to pre-process the data for visualisation with the matplotlib and I am not sure if there is a more performant way or even "on-the-fly" processing to efficiently get the same result as the code below returns (df is a pandas dataframe):

```
def calculate(s):
cl = 100 if s["income-class"] == "<=50K" else 300
return cl


df["incomeClassNum"] = df.apply(lambda row: calculate(row), axis=1)

plt.scatter(df[["age"]], df[["education-num"]], s=df["incomeClassNum"])
plt.show()
```

Thanks for any advice and feedback,
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vectorized [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df["incomeClassNum"] = np.where(df["income-class"] == "<=50K", 100, 300)

plt.scatter(df["age"], df["education-num"], s=df["incomeClassNum"])
```

Also it seems new column is not necessary:

```
incomeClassNum = np.where(df["income-class"] == "<=50K", 100, 300)

plt.scatter(df["age"], df["education-num"], s=incomeClassNum )
```